# Make background fog effect with html canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

How to make fog background effect with canvas like in snippet. I try to make fog effect without draw new image. If remove draw new image fog stay on screen. How to make only fog transition without adding new image from canvas. Fog comes from center, disappear out side of window.

```js
const canv = document.getElementById("canvas"),
      ctx = canv.getContext("2d"),
      img = new Image(),
      imgMask = new Image();

let W = window.innerWidth -10;
let H = window.innerHeight -10;
canv.height = H;
canv.width = W;
imgMask.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkcygpizo/image/upload/v1505176017/codepen/cloud-texture.png";
img.src = "http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/city-wallpaper-7.jpg";

let speed = 0;
let requestId;

function draw() {
  speed += 20;

  const maskX = (canv.width - (70 + speed)) / 2,
        maskY = (canv.height - (40 + speed)) / 2;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

  ctx.drawImage(imgMask, maskX, maskY, 70 + speed, 40 + speed);
    
// ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
// ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, W, H);

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, W, H);
  
  requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

window.onload = () => {
  canv.width = W;
  canv.height = H;

  setTimeout(() => {
    draw();
  }, 20);
}
```

```css
.image {
     width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      display: block;
}
#canvas {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
<img src="https://superdevresources.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/new-york-background.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. I have to admit it's still very unclear to me what you are after. From which state to which state do you want to transition? Your current effect works by compositing the fog image with the next image, if you don't have the next image, then there is no possible compositing => only the fog would be visible. https://jsfiddle.net/6jzudL8o/

Comment: yes, after 2 second of animation fog need to disappear and remains html content. Now fog is visible and that is issue.